# Java : how to determine disk space on Windows system prior to 1.6

Tags: java, windows, diskspace

I want to determine the available disk space on windows. I don't care that my code is not portable. I use this :

```
String[] command = {"dir",drive};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
InputStream result = process.getInputStream();
```

aiming to parse the result from a "dir C:" type of call, but the String I get from the command line call is as if I called dir with a `/W` option (not giving any information about file sizes or disk usage / free space). (Although when I launch `dir C:` directly from the command line, I get the expected result, so there is no `dir` particular setup on my system.) Trying to pass a token `/-W` or on any other option seems not to work : I just get the name of the folders/files contained in the drive, but no other information whatsoever.

Someone knows a fix / workaround ?

**NOTE:**

I can't go along the `fsutil` route, because `fsutil` does not work on network drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your `exec()` is finding a program called "dir" somewhere in your path because with your `String[] command` as it is I would otherwise expect you to get an `IOException (The system cannot find the file specified)`. The standard dir command is built into the cmd.exe Command Prompt and is not a standalone program you can execute in its own right.

To run the dir command built into cmd.exe you need to use the /c switch on cmd.exe which executes the specified command and then exits. So if you want to execute:

```
cmd /c dir
```

your arguments to pass to exec would be:

```
String[] command = { "cmd", "/c", "dir", drive };
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I got the solution from Apache Commons IO, but didn't know the explanation behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about portability, use the [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202455) method from Win32 API. Wrap it using JNI, and viola!

Your Java code should look like:

```
public native long getFreeSpace(String driveName);
```

and the rest can be done through the example [here](http://patriot.net/%7Etvalesky/jninative.html). I think that while JNI has its performance problems, it is less likely to cause the amount of [pain you'll endure](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6474073) by using the Process class....

Comment: Or use JNA to avoid the complexities of JNI compilation and setup.

Comment: -0.5 Violas are not supported by Java :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons has [FileSystemUtils.freeSpaceKb()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html#freeSpaceKb%28java.lang.String%29) that will work cross platfrom etc etc